# Is there any Email Already Exists in Asp.net functionality with validator?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ajax

My requirement is, if user enters email in asp.net textbox, it should validate from database, either this email exists or not, and should stop from submitting the form, is there any built in functionality or i have to make myself?

Thanks
Atif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do it yourself. You can use AJAX as follows:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" MaxLength="50"
        AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtEmail_Changed"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv" runat="Server" 
        ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
        CssClass="ValidationError" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email"
        ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMessage" runat="Server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtEmail" EventName="TextChanged" />
       </Triggers>
   <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>

protected void txtEmail_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // Write your code to check from DB
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally do it like this :

```
SqlConnection myConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=stuff Integrated Security=True"
SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [email] FROM [dbo].[dbo].[dbo];", myConnection1);
SqlDataReader reader = myCommand1.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing, as far as I know (moreover, where should the email uniqueness be checked? in a database? an Active Directory domain?)

You have to define your own validator control, inheriting from the [BaseValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.aspx) class.