# How to show a error when a modal popup extender is active

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have a `ModalPopupExtender` to create new users. When the user enters the new user details and tries to enter the same email Id which is already registered then I want to show a error.

Create user:

```
  if (emailcount != 0)
            {
                
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "UserDialogScript", 

"alert(\"User already exists!\");", true);
            }
```

I check whether the email is already used, if it is used I want to pop up the error but the page stays still with the ModalPopupExtender on the top. I am not able to do anything after that. How can I display the error?

Comment: I think is best to show a label, inside the popup extender, with the error message you want to display. That way you don't have to spit out javascript code.

Comment: Similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340314/is-there-any-email-already-exists-in-asp-net-functionality-with-validator


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340314/is-there-any-email-already-exists-in-asp-net-functionality-with-validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a different approach for this. In your modal popup extender, try something like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlUserDetails" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtEmail_OnTextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="lblEmailMessage" runat="server" Text="Already exists!" Visible="false" /> 
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the code-behind:

```
protected void txtEmail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check for matching email address and show label if match is found
    lblEmailMessage.Visible = FindMatchingEmailAddress(txtEmail.Text.Trim());    

    //clear the email input if a match is found??
    txtEmail.Text = String.Empty;
}
```